# How to access the R+Shiny code for the applications on shinyapps.io?

Tags: css, r, user-interface, shiny, shiny-server

I have found a very well-design shiny app on [shinyapps.io](https://wuli.shinyapps.io/QuoiR/) website but I am not sure how to access its `R` code or say the `github` directory for its code. I find it very instructive if we could have access to its code. Anyways, in the worst case, can someone help me to know how can I have nice sidebarPanels and mainPanels like this website? I know some `CSS` is involved but I am new to `CSS` and not sure how to get some neat design like that in shiny.

Comment: the [panel css](https://wuli.shinyapps.io/QuoiR/_w_8b611eff/css/panels.css) and the page source `view-source:https://wuli.shinyapps.io/QuoiR/` --  copy-paste  in chrome. the r repo is well hidden

Comment: @rawr is correct. ShinyApps keeps the R code behind the applications private. You can view the publicly visible things like JavaScript and CSS, but you wouldn't be able to get the source code of the app without identifying and contacting the author.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know how the app looked (the app is down) but I guess you should take a look at "[shinydashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/)". That gives you a very nice side and main panels.