# R web app - without user seeing code

Tags: r, shiny

I'm interested in writing a R web app, and have been looking into Shiny, but, it seems that the end-user can see my code, which I wouldn't want. Any suggestions to accomplish this? Or alternatives to Shiny?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think in the contrary that one cannot see what code is behind a shiny application. I once used a `textInput` and turned it into a password check before running the rest of the app

Comment: Check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/28465597/3871924 and one of the comments is written by someone working at RStudio @Jeff Allen

Comment: Also have a look at the this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659943/disabling-inspect-element-right-click-and-f12-in-google-chrome